# Ist "eine Nachbarin von mir" falsch?

Tags: word-usage

Soweit ich weiß sagt man "*ein Freund von mir*". Der Ausdruck "*eine Nachbarin von mir*" klingt für mein Ohr dagegen etwas seltsam. Wie kann man das ausdrücken?

Comment: Genau so - es ist egal, ob Du von Freunden, Nachbarinnen oder meinetwegen Schuhen redest. Es ist eine umgangssprachliche, völlig normale Formulierung.

Comment: @Stephie ...ich finde da nichts Umgangssprachliches dran. "Eine meiner Nachbarinnen" ist bei weitem zu "geschraubt", und gerade bei der Nachbarin (im Vergleich zum Schuh...) halte ich den possessiven Genitiv für möglicherweise etwas gewagt.

Comment: Und, schon Google bemüht?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

An

> eine Nachbarin von mir

ist nichts auszusetzen.

> Walter, der links von mir steht, ist **ein Freund von mir.** Lisa, an meiner rechten Seite, ist **eine Nachbarin von mir.** Außerdem ist hier auch noch Heinrich, **ein Kollege von mir.** Maria, die dort hinten steht, ist **eine Cousine von mir.**

Man kann das aber auch so formulieren:

> Walter, der links von mir steht, ist **einer meiner Freunde.** Lisa, an meiner rechten Seite, ist **eine meiner Nachbarinnen.** Außerdem ist hier auch noch Heinrich, **einer meiner Kollegen.** Maria, die dort hinten steht, ist **eine meiner Cousinen.**

Diese Variante setzt aber voraus, dass es in jeder Kategorie mehrere Personen gibt. (Wer sagt »Maria ist eine meiner Cousinen« sagt implizit auch: »Ich habe außer Maria auch noch andere Cousinen«). Wenn man sagt »Maria ist eine Cousine von mir« lässt man offen, ob Maria die einzige Cousine ist, oder ob man mehrere Cousinen hat.

Aber auch das kann man sagen:

> Walter, der links von mir steht, ist **mein Freund.** Lisa, an meiner rechten Seite, ist **meine Nachbarin.** Außerdem ist hier auch noch Heinrich, **mein Kollege.** Maria, die dort hinten steht, ist **meine Cousine.**

Hier gibt es aber subtile Bedeutungsunterschiede:

- **Walter ist mein Freund.**
  Das kann man deuten als »Walter ist mein einziger Freund«, oder auch als »Walter ist mein bester und intimster Freund«. Je nach Kontext ist auch die Interpretation »Walter ist mein Lebensgefährte« möglich. Das liegt ab der besonderen Mehrdeutigkeit des Wortes *»Freund«*.
- **Lisa ist meine Nachbarin; Heinrich ist mein Kollege, Maria ist meine Cousine**
  Hier klingt nichts besonderes mit. Weder, das Lisa die einzige Nachbarin wäre, noch dass sie unter allen Nachbarn etwas besonderes wäre. Sinngemäß gilt das gleiche für Heinrich und Maria. Das man hier keine Besonderheit heraushört, liegt daran, das die Wörter *Nachbarin, Kollege* und *Cousine* keine Mehrdeutigkeit aufweisen.

Diese Mehrdeutigkeit von *Freund* (»guter Freund« vs. »Lebensgefährte«) ist vermutlich der Grund, warum »ein Freund von mir« geläufiger ist als »eine Nachbarin von mir«. Denn es ist einfacher zu sagen »meine Nachbarin«, denn das bedeute dasselbe. Aber »mein Freund« bedeutet etwas anderes als »ein Freund von mir«, daher kann »ein Freund von mir« nicht durch »mein Freund« ersetzt werden.

Comment: Ich kann auch in der Pampa leben, wo ich nur eine Nachbarin habe, und Fred kann mehrere beste Freunde haben, die aber nichts voneinander wissen dürfen. Wenn "mein Freund" "Schatz" bedeuten soll, so muss man das aus dem Kontext wissen - die sprachliche Markierung "ist mein Freund" gibt es nicht her.

Comment: Meiner Schwester ihr Freund sagt aber, dass "dem Fritz seine Nachbarin" (und auch "eine Nachbarin von mir") keine gute Formulierung ist, wenn man beim **schriftlich** Kommunizieren ist. Mündlich kann es je nach Region natürlich total normal sein.